# Richfaces 4.5.2 + JSF 2.2.6 getting $.blockUI is not a function

Tags: jquery, jsf

Getting `$.blockUI is not a function` error when I try to use a progressive dropdown.

The first ajax call is called but when I try second time, it is blocked.

I tried debugging option and got the $.blockUI error.

Version of jQuery is 1.8.13.

Can anyone tell whether there is a compatibility issue with Richfaces and jquery or some-other issue? I tried changing the jquery-ui version to 1.11.13 but no change observed.

Below is the code for reference.

```
 <t:selectOneMenu value="#{filingEditor.importerGci}"
                        rendered="#{selectedFiling.newFiling}">
                        <f:param name="conversationId" value="#{conversation.id}" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="$unassigned$"
                            itemLabel="#{msg.unassigned_value}" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="$more$" itemLabel="More..." />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="$separator$"
                            itemLabel="#{msg.select_menu_empty}" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{filingEditor.favoriteImporters}" />

                        <f:ajax event="change"
                            actionListener="#{filingEditor.changeImporter}"
                            onsubmit="changeImporter(this)"
                            reRender="#{id}_eiimporter"
                            ajaxSingle="true" status="ei_status" />
                    </t:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: I don't even see the text "blockUI" in the markup you have provided, so I'm guessing the error originates from som other piece of code or marmup than what you have provided here.

Comment: Though I am not using the blokUI directly in my code, I am getting the error while I debug and it is also seen in the viewsource. Will richfaces or jsf core internally invoke blockUI for any ajax calls?

Comment: If you don't use blockUI directly, then some of your library code must have that as a dependency or just contain a bug. Can you provide the source code where you see the blockUI call?

Comment: Following is the code that calls blockUI  <br/>
<!-- language: lang-js -->                                                       ;if(d.blockUI){d.unblockUI();d("body").append(this.dpDiv)}}this._inDialog=false}},_tidyDialog:function(a){a.dpDiv.removeClass(this._dialogClass).unbind(".ui-datepicker-calendar")},_checkExternalClick:function(a)  <br/>                            The Following error I am getting using a4j:log  <br/> richfaces.queue: ajax submit error: Object doesn't support property or method 'blockUI'

Comment: Wait, you're using RichFaces and you've manually added jQuery..? Do you realize that this will only end up in conflicts? You're supposed to just use RichFaces-bundled jQuery. Cleanup one and other and retry.

Comment: I have migrated from jsf 1.2 (with ajax4jsf) to jsf 2.2.6 (with richfaces 4.5.2). In the jsf 1.2 version, the jquery js files were part of the source. As I have Richfaces-bundled jQuery, I have cleanedup the jQuery js files present in source. Eventhough I am getting the same blockUI error. should I need to do anyother modification?

Comment: i am getting the same error "$blockui is not a function" even after removing all  the jquery files from my source. Is there a specific way to invoke the jquery in richfaces? currently, using , '$.blockui'. can u pls advise whether this is a pbm with jquery loading conflict or the way invoked is wrong?